# GIT remote server backup onto aws server

Tags: git, amazon-s3, backup

Need you help in getting the correct approach to sync/backup all my remote repositories located at one server to another aws server. Basically I need to take a backup on regular basis and host it on aws server. This aws server is going to be used simply for backing up the GIT and not for regular git pushes/pull`s.

Let me know how we can achieve this from remote server to sync all data including remote branches, tags to another server on very frequent basis.

Answer (score 0):

Open bare repository on the remote AWS machine, set it as a remote on the local repo, and do a "git push --all" every day/hour/whenever you want.

Comment: or make it a cronjob or even a git hook on the primary aws server so you do not have to remember to run it locally from time to time.